# Matrix exponentiation of an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations, matrix-decomposition, matrix-exponential

How can an orthogonal matrix be expressed in an exponential matrix? 
If A be an orthogonal matrix, how can A be written as the exponential of a matrix S : 
A = exp(S)

Comment: Here's a start: Show that $\exp(S)$ is orthogonal when $S$ is skew-symmetric. To find a specific $S$ that works for $A$ it's easiest to know something about how you can write a general orthogonal matrix as a product of rotations in orthogonal $2$-dimensional planes.

Comment: A warning: It sounds like you are working over $\mathbb{R}$. Not every orthogonal matrix can be expressed in this form if you restrict to $S$ being real. The simplest counter example is that $-1 \neq e^s$ for any real $s$. This is not an issue if $S$ is allowed to be complex.

Comment: S is allowed to be complex, but that's not my problem, my problem is how to find that S that expresses A.